# boat in a river algebra problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The near stagnant river flowed at only 2 miles per hour. Harold's boat
>   could go 56 miles down the river in one-half the time it took to go 80
>   miles up the river. What was the speed of his boat in still water.

not sure how to display the one half time in the equation.

Comment: A non-math comment: 2 miles per hour is hardly "near stagnant".

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

- If the speed of the boat is $v$ in still water, what is the speed
  river downawards, and what is the speed of the boat river upwards?
- If you know the speed and the distance, what can you say of the time
  needed for each voyage?
- How do the times relate?

Now go solve for $v$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the speed of his boat be $v \text{ mph}$. When going up a distance of $80$ miles, the time taken is $t = \dfrac{80}{v-2}$. We are also given that when going down a distance of $56$ miles, the time taken is $t/2$, i.e., we have
$$\dfrac{t}2 = \dfrac{56}{v+2} = \dfrac12 \cdot \dfrac{80}{v-2} \implies \dfrac7{v+2} = \dfrac5{v-2} \implies 7v-14 = 5v+10 \implies v=12 \text{ mph}$$

Comment: How would you work it out like this?